# Rename multiple tables with single command

Tags: mysql, oracle, rename

It's possible with mysql as mentioned here:

https://www.electrictoolbox.com/rename-multiple-tables-mysql/

Does similar action possible with oracle ?

Something like :

```
Alter table tbl1 rename to new1, tbl2 to new2;
```

Comment: it is not possible but if you have too much table you can do this with a function or procedure.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which I could think of is you can generate multiple `ALTER` commands using a single `select` from `ALL_TABLES`.

```
SELECT 'Alter table '
  ||table_name
  ||' rename to '
  ||table_name
  ||'_NEW'
  ||rn||';' Alter_command
FROM
  (SELECT ROWNUM rn ,
    a.*
  FROM ALL_TABLES a
  WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('<LIST_OF_TABLES>')
  ) ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Output:

```
Alter table ABCD_TMP rename to ABCD_TMP_NEW1509;
Alter table ABCD_TMP3 rename to ABCD_TMP3_NEW1510;
Alter table ACCESS$ rename to ACCESS$_NEW46;
Alter table ACCOUNT rename to ACCOUNT_NEW1549;
Alter..
.....
```

Comment: Hi @Kaushil Nayak, I have the tables names, the generate is not needed here, I just want to apply the rename in single command instead of several. Thanks.